# Angular get label of data-ng-options but pass value to ng-model

Tags: angularjs, angular-ngmodel

Id like to pass the value of the `data-ng-options` to the `ng-model` but get the label of the value to display on the span as below , How would i go about it ?

**View**

```
<tr ng-repeat="choice in vm.choices">
    <td>
        <span>@{{choice.department }}</span>
      <div class="form-group">
         <div class="input-group">
          <select data-ng-options=
                'd.value as d.label for d in vm.departments' ng-model="choice.department">
                    </select>
         </div>
      </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

**controller**

```
vm.departments = [
            {value:0, label:'DENTAL'},
            {value:1, label:'PYCHOLOGY'}

          ];
```

id like the label ie 'DENTAL' to display on the `span` but pass the value ie `0` to the `ng-model`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Storing the value only in the `ng-model` makes no sense.  Storing the object is the standard method when dealing with an array of objects in a dropdown.

Consider the following:

```html
<span>@{{choice.department.value }}</span>
<span>{{choice.department.label}}</span>
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="input-group">
    <select data-ng-options='d.label for d in vm.departments' 
            ng-model="choice.department">
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/MGIvAAhiSsgkxSXpwTWZ?p=preview

You have access to all the properties of the object to use for whatever you need.

The difference here is in the way that the ng-options is structured. By not supplying an `as` clause, the entire object is assigned to the `ng-model` parameter, instead of a specific property from the object.

Comment: what do you mean? it worked correctly in the plunker I provided?

Comment: Does not work in plucker , kindly check again , id like the `choice.department.label`

Comment: hmm I'm sorry I'm not sure how the plunker has the original code from your question and not the update that I posted in the answer, let me fix that.  The difference is in the way that the `ng-options` is written.

Comment: the changed plunker is at http://plnkr.co/edit/MGIvAAhiSsgkxSXpwTWZ?p=preview.  I'll put the new link in the question as well, with a bit more explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Transform the array into object looking like this:

```
{
  0: 'DENTAL',
  1: 'PSYCHOLOGY'
}
```

and store it in separate scope variable (let's say `dict`), then in template use:

```
{{dict[choice.department]}}
```

Comment: if you would please use code example ie the scope `dict` , as i am using scope `vm` as above